# weird css conflict cant find the cause

Tags: css

Hi guys i have a script that i would like to use for my website.

Source: https://codepen.io/jackrugile/pen/ABeIi

```
<head>
<style>
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin:400);

.webdesigntuts-workshop {
    background: #151515;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.webdesigntuts-workshop:before,
.webdesigntuts-workshop:after {
    content: '';
    display: block; 
    height: 1px;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0 0 0 -400px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 800px;
}

.webdesigntuts-workshop:before {
    background: #444;
    background: linear-gradient(left, #151515, #444, #151515);
    top: 192px;
}

.webdesigntuts-workshop:after {
    background: #000;
    background: linear-gradient(left, #151515, #000, #151515);  
    top: 191px;
}

.webdesigntuts-workshop form {
    background: #111;
    background: linear-gradient(#1b1b1b, #111);
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #272727;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0px;
    margin: 150px auto 0;
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.webdesigntuts-workshop input {
    background: #222;   
    background: linear-gradient(#333, #222);    
    border: 1px solid #444;
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 0 #000;
    color: #888;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-family: 'Cabin', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 400;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 10px;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
    width: 200px;
}

.ie .webdesigntuts-workshop input {
    line-height: 40px;
}

.webdesigntuts-workshop input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: #888;
}

.webdesigntuts-workshop input:-moz-placeholder {
   color: #888;
}

.webdesigntuts-workshop input:focus {
    animation: glow 800ms ease-out infinite alternate;
    background: #222922;
    background: linear-gradient(#333933, #222922);
    border-color: #393;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,255,0,.2), inset 0 0 5px rgba(0,255,0,.1), 0 2px 0 #000;
    color: #efe;
    outline: none;
}

.webdesigntuts-workshop input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder { 
    color: #efe;
}

.webdesigntuts-workshop input:focus:-moz-placeholder {
    color: #efe;
}

.webdesigntuts-workshop button {
    background: #222;
    background: linear-gradient(#333, #222);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #444;
    border-left-color: #000;
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 0 #000;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-family: 'Cabin', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 400;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
    width: 80px;
}   

.webdesigntuts-workshop button:hover,
.webdesigntuts-workshop button:focus {
    background: #292929;
    background: linear-gradient(#393939, #292929);
    color: #5f5;
    outline: none;
}

.webdesigntuts-workshop button:active {
    background: #292929;
    background: linear-gradient(#393939, #292929);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000, inset 1px 0 1px #222;
    top: 1px;
}

@keyframes glow {
    0% {
        border-color: #393;
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,255,0,.2), inset 0 0 5px rgba(0,255,0,.1), 0 2px 0 #000;
    }   
    100% {
        border-color: #6f6;
        box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,255,0,.6), inset 0 0 10px rgba(0,255,0,.4), 0 2px 0 #000;
    }
}

/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

</style>


<section class="webdesigntuts-workshop">
    <form action="" method="">          
        <input type="search" placeholder="What are you looking for?">               
        <button>Search</button>
    </form>
</section>
```

Now when i try to implement this script on my own index.php.
 but the search button is 2 pixels less height 38 and width 78. while the css is telling it to be 40 and 80. So i figured it might give this conflict because of other css i use on my website. I tried to reset the css by using this code on the element,

```
 .reset-this {
    animation : none;
    animation-delay : 0;
    animation-direction : normal;
    animation-duration : 0;
    animation-fill-mode : none;
    animation-iteration-count : 1;
    animation-name : none;
    animation-play-state : running;
    animation-timing-function : ease;
    backface-visibility : visible;
    background : 0;
    background-attachment : scroll;
    background-clip : border-box;
    background-color : transparent;
    background-image : none;
    background-origin : padding-box;
    background-position : 0 0;
    background-position-x : 0;
    background-position-y : 0;
    background-repeat : repeat;
    background-size : auto auto;
    border : 0;
    border-style : none;
    border-width : medium;
    border-color : inherit;
    border-bottom : 0;
    border-bottom-color : inherit;
    border-bottom-left-radius : 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius : 0;
    border-bottom-style : none;
    border-bottom-width : medium;
    border-collapse : separate;
    border-image : none;
    border-left : 0;
    border-left-color : inherit;
    border-left-style : none;
    border-left-width : medium;
    border-radius : 0;
    border-right : 0;
    border-right-color : inherit;
    border-right-style : none;
    border-right-width : medium;
    border-spacing : 0;
    border-top : 0;
    border-top-color : inherit;
    border-top-left-radius : 0;
    border-top-right-radius : 0;
    border-top-style : none;
    border-top-width : medium;
    bottom : auto;
    box-shadow : none;
    box-sizing : content-box;
    caption-side : top;
    clear : none;
    clip : auto;
    color : inherit;
    columns : auto;
    column-count : auto;
    column-fill : balance;
    column-gap : normal;
    column-rule : medium none currentColor;
    column-rule-color : currentColor;
    column-rule-style : none;
    column-rule-width : none;
    column-span : 1;
    column-width : auto;
    content : normal;
    counter-increment : none;
    counter-reset : none;
    cursor : auto;
    direction : ltr;
    display : inline;
    empty-cells : show;
    float : none;
    font : normal;
    font-family : inherit;
    font-size : medium;
    font-style : normal;
    font-variant : normal;
    font-weight : normal;
    height : auto;
    hyphens : none;
    left : auto;
    letter-spacing : normal;
    line-height : normal;
    list-style : none;
    list-style-image : none;
    list-style-position : outside;
    list-style-type : disc;
    margin : 0;
    margin-bottom : 0;
    margin-left : 0;
    margin-right : 0;
    margin-top : 0;
    max-height : none;
    max-width : none;
    min-height : 0;
    min-width : 0;
    opacity : 1;
    orphans : 0;
    outline : 0;
    outline-color : invert;
    outline-style : none;
    outline-width : medium;
    overflow : visible;
    overflow-x : visible;
    overflow-y : visible;
    padding : 0;
    padding-bottom : 0;
    padding-left : 0;
    padding-right : 0;
    padding-top : 0;
    page-break-after : auto;
    page-break-before : auto;
    page-break-inside : auto;
    perspective : none;
    perspective-origin : 50% 50%;
    position : static;
    /* May need to alter quotes for different locales (e.g fr) */
    quotes : '\201C' '\201D' '\2018' '\2019';
    right : auto;
    tab-size : 8;
    table-layout : auto;
    text-align : inherit;
    text-align-last : auto;
    text-decoration : none;
    text-decoration-color : inherit;
    text-decoration-line : none;
    text-decoration-style : solid;
    text-indent : 0;
    text-shadow : none;
    text-transform : none;
    top : auto;
    transform : none;
    transform-style : flat;
    transition : none;
    transition-delay : 0s;
    transition-duration : 0s;
    transition-property : none;
    transition-timing-function : ease;
    unicode-bidi : normal;
    vertical-align : baseline;
    visibility : visible;
    white-space : normal;
    widows : 0;
    width : auto;
    word-spacing : normal;
    z-index : auto;
    /* basic modern patch */
    all: initial;
    all: unset;
}

/* basic modern patch */

#reset-this-root {
    all: initial;
    * {
        all: unset;
    }
}
```

But sadly, reseting all the css doesn't solve the problem. I know a workaround just add 2 pixels to both width and height, but i would rather find out why it has this behavior.

Hope anyone can help.

Yours sincerely,

C
[Input field X Y][1]
[Button X Y][2]

Image 1 Why are these different? https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dhyW.png
 Image 2 Why are these different? https://i.stack.imgur.com/XA6jc.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button is fine for me, it's the input that is taller because of borders.

Just add at the start of your css :

```
*, *::before, *::after {box-sizing: border-box;}
```

And everything will fit like you want.

Comment: i added this code, but it didnt do anything? There is something weird going on, i actually added 2 images to make the problem more clear. I updated my orginal post on top.

Comment: It should work. I added it in the dev console to see if it fix thing and it did. You could refresh with cache purged ? Be sure this property is not directly on your elements with the value `content-box`. Please see my answer of this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48887463/100vh-and-100vw-compared-to-the-current-size-of-the-browser-window/48887528#48887528

Answer (score 1):

There is a `border: 1px solid #444;` setting and `box-sizing: border-box` which includes that border into the defined width. So if width is 80px, there will be 2 x 1px (both sides) less width (= 78px) for the actual contents. Same for height.

Comment: Hello, i tried to remove those 2 settings from the css. This didnt help at all. Still the button is 2 pixels off the orginal css

Comment: I would leave it in, but look for other `box-sizing` settings in your page which might have an influence

Comment: is there a way to first reset the box-sizing to its orginal value.

Comment: I am not completely sure what you mean / want to achieve, but the default setting for box-sizing is `box-sizing: content-box` - you can add that...

Comment: look at the images i added on my orginal code, you understand what my problem is?

Comment: Hmm - I would say the in the screenshot where you selected the input, the developer tools simply show the wrong  box model values  (i.e. those of the button - I really don'T know why, but it's obvious that this is displayed wrong). And concerning the button itself: On the screen you see that it occupies 80px horizontally, in the box model graphic you see that it has 78px inner width plus 2 x 1px borders, which adds up to 80px (similar for height)